# How to limit NSXMLParser to elements after a given element

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

The way this XML is formed below, my code is getting both the n13 time periods as well as the n7 time periods, is it possible to limit my results to only the n13 data somehow?

```
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="12hourly">
<layout-key>k-p12h-n13-1</layout-key>
<start-valid-time period-name="This Afternoon">2016-06-30T12:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Tonight">2016-06-30T18:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Friday">2016-07-01T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Friday Night">2016-07-01T18:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Saturday">2016-07-02T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Saturday Night">2016-07-02T18:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday">2016-07-03T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday Night">2016-07-03T18:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Independence Day">2016-07-04T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Monday Night">2016-07-04T18:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Tuesday">2016-07-05T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Tuesday Night">2016-07-05T18:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Wednesday">2016-07-06T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
</time-layout>
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="12hourly">
<layout-key>k-p24h-n7-1</layout-key>
<start-valid-time period-name="This Afternoon">2016-06-30T12:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Friday">2016-07-01T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Saturday">2016-07-02T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday">2016-07-03T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Independence Day">2016-07-04T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Tuesday">2016-07-05T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Wednesday">2016-07-06T06:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
</time-layout>
```

my DidStartElement code:

```
 if weAreInsideAnItem == true {

            if  (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("start-valid-time") {

                if let periodAsNSString: NSString = attributeDict["period-name"] {
                    guard let periodAsString: String = periodAsNSString as String else {return}
                    tempForecastTimes.append(periodAsString)

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you loop over the nodes ?

Comment: Unrelated, but the `if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("foo") { ... }` pattern can be simplified to `if elementName == "foo" { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In processing element named `layout-key`, see if its value was equal to something, e.g. `k-p12h-n13-1`, and if so, set some state variable, e.g. `isInN13`. Then, when processing `start-valid-time` you can then consider that state variable. For example:

```
var value: String?
var isInN13 = false

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if elementName == "layout-key" {
        value = ""
    }

    if elementName == "start-valid-time" && isInN13 {
        value = ""
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    value? += string
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "layout-key" {
        isInN13 = value == "k-p12h-n13-1"
    }

    if elementName == "start-valid-time" && isInN13 {
        print(value)
    }

    value = nil
}
```